Error 404 while calling customised assistant with ChatGPT API in R
To analyse sentences, I've trained a ChatGPT assistant that I'm calling from an R function to classify sentences:
library(openai)

Sys.setenv(
  OPENAI_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)

score_sentence_CSM <- function(mySentence) {
  
  myScore <- create_chat_completion(
    
    model = "asst_3JVWE1StXCNELM4PBbJrDe8O",
    temperature = 0.5,
    messages = list(
      list(
        "role" = "system",
        "content" = "You are a helpful assistant"
      ),
      list(
        "role" = "user",
        "content" = paste("How to classify the following sentence according to your instructions (your answer is only a number): ", mySentence)
      )
    )
  )
  
  return(myScore[["choices"]][["message.content"]])
  
}

score_sentence_CSM("The future is bright")

The code returns the following error:

Error: OpenAI API request failed [404]:
The model asst_3JVWE1StXCNELM4PBbJrDe8O does not exist or you do not have access to it.

The function return an answer when the model = "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k"
The custom assistant works from openai playground
Should I change something to the code or is there something specific to be done in the configuration of the assistant?

Where is the model asst_3JVWE1StXCNELM4PBbJrDe8O? Are you sure it exists?

The model is visible on my openai dashboard on https://platform.openai.com/assistants and I can use it from the playground.
